# Structure of a subspace

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, geometry

Let $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ be the canonical vectors in $\mathbb R^n$. Fix an integer $k<n$
and define $v_{1}=e_1+e_2+\ldots+e_k$,

$v_{2}=e_1+e_3+\ldots+e_{k+1}$,

$\ldots$

$v_{n-k+1}=e_1+e_{n-k+2}+\ldots+e_{n}$

(Notice each vector is a linear combination of $k$ canonical vectors)

Show that if $e_{i_1}+e_{i_2}+\ldots+e_{i_m} \in \text{span}\{ v_1, v_2, \ldots v_{n-k+1}\}$, then $m\geq k$.

I am trying induction in $n$ to get a contradiction. For $i_m<n$ it follows by induction. So we can assume $i_m=n$, but I cannot figure out a pattern for all cases. Any help would be much appreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Consider some random $x\in\text{span}\{v_{1},v_{2},...,v_{k}\}$. We can find $\lambda_{1},...,\lambda_{k}\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$x=\sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_{i}v_{i}.$$
Note that $x\in\text{span}\{e_{1},...,e_{2k-1}\}$ hence we can find $\mu_{1},...,\mu_{2k-1}\in\mathbb{R}$ such that
$$x=\sum^{2k-1}_{i=1}\mu_{i}e_{i}.$$
As $\lambda_{i}v_{i}=\lambda_{i}e_{1}+\lambda_{i}e_{i+1}+...+\lambda_{i}e_{i+k-1}$ we find that 
$$\sum_{i=1}^{k}\lambda_{i}v_{i}=\sum^{k}_{i=1}\lambda_{i}e_{1}+\lambda_{i}e_{i+1}+...+\lambda_{i}e_{i+k-1}=\sum^{2k-1}_{i=1}\mu_{i}e_{i}.$$
So
$$m=\sum^{2k-1}_{i=1}\mu_{i}=k\sum^{k}_{i=1}\lambda_{i}.$$
Furthermore, since $\mu_{1}=\sum^{k}_{i=1}\lambda_{i}$ we have that
$$\mu_{1}=\frac{m}{k}.$$
Since by design $\mu_{1}=0$ or $\mu_{1}=1$ we have that $m=k$ and $\mu_{1}=1$. This is only if $i_{s}=i_{t}$ if and only $s=t$, Otherwise we have that $\mu_{1}\in\mathbb{N}$ and $k$ divides $m$, for which we certainly have $m\geq k$.

Comment: I think you mean $\lambda_i v_i=\lambda_i e_1+\lambda_i  e_{i+1}+\ldots+\lambda_i  e_{k+i-1}$. I cannot see how this implies the second equality $=k \sum \lambda_i$. Notice that the coefficient of $e_2$ is $\lambda_1$.

Comment: I've expanded my answer a bit to clarify, the idea is that in the sum of all $\mu_{i}$, for every $j$, $\lambda_{j}$ will pop up $k$ times and no more, so while calculating individual $\mu_{i}$ is hard, the sum is very easy.

Comment: Nice. It seems correct. I changed the question a bit, due to a typo in the indices. Now the space is generated by all possible vectors. Do you think the same argument carries over?

Comment: Yes, the only thing that changes is the bounds of the sum. You still end up with $\mu_{1}=\frac{m}{k}$.

Comment: We have $m=k \sum_{i=1}^n \lambda_i = k \mu_1$. Because we only care about $x$ where $m\geq 1$ and $\mu_i \in \{0,1\}$, we have $\mu_1 =1$. Therefore, $m=k$.

Comment: That is, $\mu_i$  is never zero and $m=k$ for all such $x$.

Comment: If you meant $\mu_{1}$ is never $0$, then yes. ($\mu_{i}$ in general obviously can be $0$.)